# How does maplist work in a program that inserts elements into an AVL Tree

Tags: prolog

I am studying Prolog and I could not follow the lessons so I have some doubts relating to a particular use of the **maplist** built in SWI Prolog predicate.

So let me explain my situation:

I have a personal predicate named **`addavl(Tree/Height, Element, NewTree/Height)`** that insert the element **`Element`** into the AVL tree **`Tree`** (where **`Height`** is the height of this original tree) and generate a new AVL tree named **`NewTree`** that contains **`Element`** and that have a new height **`Height`**

Now I have a list of elements and I would add these elements to an AVL tree (that at the beginning is void), so I have the following predicate (that work fine).

I have some doubts related to the use of **`maplist/4`** SWI Prolog built in predicate and I would also know if my general interpretation of all this predicate is correct or if am I missing something.

```prolog
/* Predicate that from a given list of elements build an AVL Tree: */
buildTree(List,Tree):- 
  length(List, N),  % N: the number of element in List

  /* Create L1 as a list that have the same number of element of List
     For example if List have N=4 element L1=[A,B,C,D] where A,B,C,D
     are variable that are not yet set 
  */
  length(L1,N),           

  /* Se fosse: append(L1,[Tree],NewList) otterrei: NewList=[A,B,C,D|Tree]
     ma essendo NewList=[_|L2] so L2=[B,C,D|Tree]
     */
  append(L1,[Tree],[_|L2]), 

  /* Put the couple (nil,0) in the L1 head so I have that A=(nil,0) that
     represents an empty AVL tree:
     */
  L1=[nil/0 |_],

  /* Call addavl passing as parameter the tree in the L1 head, the value
     to insert in the List Head and the head of L2 as the current new Tree-
     When the variable Tree is reached it represents the final AVL tree
     */
  maplist(addavl, L1, List, L2).
```

My interpretation of the entire predicate is the following one:

First **`N`** variable contains the length of the original element list **`List`** that I would to insert in the AVL tree

Then is created a new list **`L1`** that have the **same number of element** of the original list **`List`**, but in this case `L1` contains variables that are not yet set up with a value.

So for example, if the original element list is:
**`List = [5, 8, 3, 4]`** the `L1` list will be something like: **`L1 = [A, B, C, D]`** 
where `A, B, C, D` are variables that are not yet valorized.

Now there is this statement that must be satisfied:

```
append(L1,[Tree],[_|L2]),
```

that I read in this way:

if I had **`append(L1,[Tree],NewList)`** instead the previous statement I would have that:

**`NewList = [A,B,C,D,Tree]`** where `A,B,C,D` are the previous not set variable of the `L1` List and **`Tree`** is a new not set variable.

But in my case I have that **`NewList = [_|L2]`** so **`L2 = [B,C,D,Tree]`**.

Now the meaning of the previous `append` operation is the creation of the `L2` list that at the beginning contains `n` not valorized variables (in the previous example 4 not valorized variables: `B,C,D`, **`Tree`**).

**Each of these variables represents a Tree in which it was inserted a new element in the original list `List`**

So, at the beginning the program put the void AVL tree in the head of this list (in my example in the `A` variable) by this instruction: `L1=[nil/0 |_]`,

So in the head of the `L1` variabile there is the void tree that have 0 as height (and a void tree is a correct AVL Tree)

And now I have the **FIRST DOUBT**: by the previous operation I have  valorized the head variable of the `L1` list but previous of this operation I have created the **`NewList=[_|L2]`** list using this statement:

```
append(L1,[Tree],[_|L2])
```

This means that the `_` anonymous variable of **`[_|L2]`** list match with **`nil/0`** AVL tree?
This work in this way also if I have valorized the `L1` head **after** that I have create the `[_|L2]` list appending `L1` list to `[Tree]`?

Ok, if my interpretation is correct go on to my **SECOND DOUBT** that it is related to how exactly work the **maplist** SWI Prolog built in predicate..

I have:

```
 maplist(addavl, L1, List, L2).
```

What exactly do this predicate?

Reading on the official documentation: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist%2F2

it seems to me that work in the following way:

I have the **`addavl`** predicate that is the **GOAL that have to be satisfied on each element of the lists**

Remembering that `addval` predicate work in this way:  `addavl(Tree/Height, Element, NewTree/Height)`.

So:

1) **`L1`** is the list of the AVL Tree (the first is the void AVL Tree: **`nil/0`**)

2) **`List`** is the original list that contain the element to insert

3) **`L2`** is the list that contains the AVL tree that I will create.

So I think that now work in the following way:

First take the void AVL Tree (**`nil/0`**) from the head of `L1`, take the first element do add from List, execute the GOAL (insert this element into the void AVL Tree) and put the result in the head of the `L2` list (that, according to my previous example, is the `B` variable, so the `B` variable contains the AVL Tree that contain the first element of the **`List`** element) <s>list**</s>

Then repeat this procedure inserting all the other elements in of the elements list **`List`** and finally, the last element of the `L2` list (the **`Tree`** variable) will represent the final AVL Tree in which all the elements were inserted.

Is my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Comment: please format your code always, using back ticks. Click on "edited [X minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16306255/revisions)" below your post to access [its editing history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16306255/revisions).

Comment: mmm what have I to do? I have not understand what you mean

Comment: ok I think that now is done

Comment: yes, you see I had to edit your question, to format it properly. Please do this yourself from now on. :) You can see *what* I edited, by accessing the editing history, so you can see the revisions there. Try it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Prolog we say "not yet instantiated variable" or "uninstantited variable".

About `L1=[nil/0 |_]`, we can call it "initializing it with an initial value".

the `_` in `[_|L2]` does indeed match the init value, and we don't care about it.

(this gives an idea of calling `append(L1, [Tree], [nil/0 | L2])`, instead of the two calls in original code).

Yes, order of operations is not important. `X=t(A), A=2` or `A=2, X=t(A)` both result in the same substitution, `A=2, X=t(2)`.

`maplist( pred, ...Lists ...)` works so that `pred` must be satisfied on elements from lists, taken pair-wise (or *by columns*). E.g. `maplist(plus, [1,2,3],[4,X,8],[5,6,Y])`.

The lists `L1` and `L2` both *share structure*:

```
nil/0   B   C   D   Tree
------------------
       L1
        -----------------
               L2
```

`maplist` sees them, and processes them, by feeding them *by columns* to `addavl`:

```
nil/0   B     C     D       % L1
 E1     E2    E3    E4      % List
 B      C     D    Tree     % L2
```

so yes, it does it like you say.

---

I don't think your teacher will accept this as an answer. You should write a direct recursive solution instead. Both variants describe same iterative computational process of progressively adding elements into a tree, using the output of previous call as input to the next. But in any given implementation one can be optimized far better than the other. Using lists, here, will most probably be less efficient than a recursive variant.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear...I will try to implement also the recursive version in these day :-) Tnx so much for your help and for your time